# Встроенная конструкция

Tags: синтаксис

(1) *Если эта карта шестёрка, **неважно какой масти**, – ты забираешь всю ставку себе.*

(2) *Наследство графа, **что ни говорите**, ему не досталось.*

Скажите, пожалуйста, есть какой-нибудь специальный термин для выделенных фрагментов? Если я не ошибаюсь, в англ. языке оно соответствует *parenthesis*, но не знаю как это по-русски.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Если эта карта шестёрка, **неважно какой масти**, – ты забираешь всю ставку себе.

Это **обособленное несогласованное определение**: неважно какой (=любой) масти.

Такой оборот можно рассматривать как вставную конструкцию с добавочным значением, но тогда его нужно обособлять скобками или тире. В данном случае используются запятые, и оборот не выделяется как вставка ни по интонации, ни по знакам препинания.

2) Наследство графа, **что ни говорите**, ему не досталось.

**Что ни говорите (устойчивый оборот)**, Разг. Экспрес. Вопреки тому, что говорится, о чём судят.

Используется в качестве **вводного сочетания** со значением уступки, например: Что ни говорите, а тяжёл наш писательский труд! Не наша это компания, не наше, что ни говорите, сословие.

Comment: Дорогая Sibylla, у меня здесь возник вопрос: в (2) "что ни говорите": я правильно понимаю, глагол "говорите" стоит в изъяв. накл.? 
в книгах еще видела сочетания с сосл. накл. "что бы вы не говорили" . так у Вас тоже говорят?

Comment: Две эти формы  (реальная и предположительная уступка) имеют одинаковое значение, но первый вариант встречается чаще:  (1) "Что ни говорите, а открытия совершают чаще всего неробеющие люди". (2) «И все-таки, что бы вы ни говорили об ограничениях разума, гений может все».  Отметим, что во втором варианте оборот может быть распространенным.

Comment: Так все-таки глагол "говорите" в "что ни говорите" стоит в изъяв. накл.?

Comment: Да, в изъявительном наклонении, у него же нет показателей сослагательного наклонения (частицы БЫ и формы прошедшего времени с суффиксом Л).

Comment: Нет нет, не сосл.накл. конечно! : ) Я сомневалась между повелит. и изъяв. 
В повелит. по-моему форма глагола тоже как "говорите" звучит

Comment: Формы совпадают, но значения разные: повелительное наклонение выражает просьбу, приказ,  а здесь значение такое: мое мнение не изменится, неважно, что вы говорите (или скажете).